# How to search on the words of a phrase using SOSL in salesforce?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I am searching on ideas in my community. I am using SOSL for this, but I have an issue regarding not searching on the exact phrase. I want to search on the words of phrase.

SOSL

```
 string searchQuery = 'FIND {'+searchText+'} IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Idea(Id, title, body, categories, createddate, lastmodifieddate)';
```

So can anybody please help me to search on the words of a phrase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using SOSL in APEX, you don't need the curly braces around the find text (they are for the API).

Assuming that you're using APEX, let's say that the phrase that you were searching for was 'awesome'. This would be the APEX syntax:

`List<Sobject[]> awesomeResults = [FIND 'awesome' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Idea(Id, title, body, categories, createddate, lastmodifieddate)'];`

If you want to create SOSL dynamically, then use the `Search.query(query_string)` method. Make sure that you escape the `'`s in your query string if you do that.

The documentation is pretty good for these features:

- [SOSL Statements](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_SOQL.htm)
- [SOSL Syntax](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_sosl_syntax.htm)
- [Dynamic SOSL](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dynamic_sosl.htm)

Comment: Adding to Sean's answer, for multiple words in a phrase, use single quotes within the FIND clause, e.g. FIND 'awesome beans'... will find all records containing both awesome and beans. I suspect you're using double quotes right now - that will search for the exact phrase "awesome beans."

Comment: Thanks Guys for replying. I am only using single quotes in my query string and i want to create SOSL dynamically. But it's doesn't make any difference. With Single Quotes it will not search the words. Ike if i want to search 'awesom words' it will not show me the results of 'Awesom'and 'words'. it just show me the results of the title which has these two words.

Comment: Have you tried separating the search terms with 'AND', e.g. FIND 'awesome AND beans'...

Comment: Search term is creating at run time. so i cant add AND in that. A user will enter a phrase but i need to split the phrase and rejoin it. I tried to do this but unfortunately sfdc doesn't gives us join functionality. so any other suggestions..

Comment: Have you tried the apex-commons library that I recommended on your other question? You can also join the array yourself by looping through the array and building a string from its elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search on the words of a phrase then your query will look like this

```
string searchQuery = 'FIND \'' +searchtext+'*\' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Idea(Id, title, body, categories, createddate, lastmodifieddate)';
```

The `searchtext` here is a string.

I think it's helpful to everybody who wants the search based on dynamic value.

Answer (score 0):

if searchText is dynamic, you can use it like this:
`:`colon before parameter searchText

```
string searchQuery = 'FIND :searchText IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Idea(Id, title, body, categories, createddate, lastmodifieddate)';
```